# How to change the point steps?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, foreach

I'm making a cv using the `altacv` from Marisa Mayers `altacv` stylesheet, I change it a lot but at one point it gets difficult, I want to use floating points in the `\foreach` loop. I tried a lot but I didn't get the solution this is the code:

```
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

\newcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
\textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
  \space{\ifnumgreater{\x}{#2}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}}\par%
}
```

I change the `\foreach` loop in 1.0,1.5,...5.0, but that didn't solve my problem. The output now is:

[image]

but I want the points in half steps till 5!

Answer (score 2):

`\cvskill` of `altacv` already supports half points:

```
\documentclass{altacv}
\begin{document}
\cvskill{Something}{5}
\cvskill{Something else}{1.5}
\cvskill{Something again}{3.5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to replicate that command in your own class, just copy it from `altacv`. In the following example I used `article` to show you can replicate it with any document class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={#2}}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
    \ifdimequal{\x pt - #2 pt}{0.5pt}%
    {\clipbox*{0pt -0.25ex {.5\width} {\totalheight}}{\color{accent}\ratingmarker}%
     \clipbox*{{.5\width} -0.25ex {\width} {\totalheight}}{\color{body!30}\ratingmarker}}
    {\ifdimgreater{\x bp}{#2 bp}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}%
  }\EndAccSupp{}\par%
}

\begin{document}
\cvskill{Something}{5}
\cvskill{Something else}{1.5}
\cvskill{Something again}{3.5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot